# Dealing with backticks in PhpStorm / WebStorm

Tags: macos, phpstorm, webstorm

We recently changed our project boilerplates for using single quotes to using backticks. Working with backticks in *Storm on OSX is not as convenient as working with single quotes, thus we tried to come up with some solutions which still lack some convenience. We're looking for further ideas to find better solutions now.

**How single quotes work in *Storm on OSX**

- typing one single quote results in two single quotes with the cursor in between ('|')
- typing afterwards results in text between the single quotes ('what has been typed')
- if 'surround selection on typing quote or brace' is true, selecting some text and typing a single quote results in
  the text being wrapped in single quotes ('some text')

**How backticks work in *Storm on OSX**

- typing one backtick results in one backtick (`), when pressing space you get two backticks with the cursor in between (`|`)
- when typing a letter, you get two backticks with the cursor in between (`|`) except if the letter is a, e, o, u, i, then you'll get (à, è, ò, ù, ì) which is quite disturbing
- when pressing space, you get two backticks with the cursor in between (`|`)
- selecting some text and typing a backtick results in a backtick (`), which is also not what we'd like to have

Comment: What do you use backticks for precisely? Quotes in comments? quotes in string literals? Because I'm not really sure how you can just 'change' into using backticks, as they have a specific, diffirent use in most cases. It can't be in code, as they're just not interchangeable, right?

Comment: @Nanne - I think its related to the template strings in JavaScript came along with the EcmaScript 2015. Where you need to use backticks to use them.

Comment: @Nanne Sorry, should've mentioned that. It is part of the ES6/ES2015 specification / featureset. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings.

Answer (score 6):

Since a backtick is a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) by default, I am struggled with the same issue.

**Live Template**

Currently I created a live template named it `--` (double-dash) for a quick which prepares a backtick-surrounded string. Below you can find the settings I used for the template:

---

*Abbreviation:* `--`

*Description:* `Backticks`

*Template text:*

```
`$0$`$END$
```

Apply: `JavaScript`

---

Unfortunately PHPStorm/Webstorm does not provide a way to toggle the quote style. Similar to the `case toggler` (*Edit -> Toggle Case*)

Answer (score 4):

**Concerning the typing**

Just use keystrokes `<backtick>` + `<space>`and type `a text` and you'll get `a text`.

**Concerning surrounding**

Create a Live Template called `backticks` with a content of `$SELECTION$`$END$, set the context to Javascript. Go to the keymap and search for 'Surround with Live Template'. Assign a key combination. Go back to the editor, select some text, press the just assigned
combination and press 'ENTER' to confirm selecting your 'backticks' template. This will wrap your text in backticks.

Comment: Have you tried pressing `Alt+Enter` (Windows/Linux) to bring quick fix menu (also accessible via "light bulb" icon) while having caret inside single quoted string? One there you may choose `Replace with template string` action to convert such string into backticks-surrounded one. **P.S.** Look related to your initial issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21750

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the quick fix hint. Sadly that's still totally inconvenient. Have to press 'Ald + Enter', 'arrow down' and Enter again.